# How I can do this using navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, listview, navigation, expandable

How can i do this please help me? It is using navigation drawer list view with sub items. How I can do this?

[image]

Comment: its a exapandable listview.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simple listview in navigation drawer u'll have to use expandable list view .
you can follow this tutorials to get basic idea
*http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/*